# Google Sheets- Formula SUMIFS with cell reference doesn't give value

Tags: google-sheets

[Google Sheet Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB5jX.png)

HI,

When i write this formula IT WORKS:

```
=SUMIFS($D$4:$D$9,$A$4:$A$9,B1,$B$4:$B$9,B2)
```

But when i write it differently, there is no result:

```
=SUMIFS($e$4:$e$9,$A$4:$A$9,B1,$B$4:$B$9,"B"&"2")
```

The result is 0.

Even when i try to reference it with row formula, As image shows, it doesn't give result:

```
=SUMIFS($D$4:$D$9,$A$4:$A$9,B1,$B$4:$B$9,"B"&row())
```

I expected to get the same result as the first code

```
=SUMIFS($D$4:$D$9,$A$4:$A$9,B1,$B$4:$B$9,B2)
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use this  `=SUMIFS($D$4:$D$9,$A$4:$A$9,B1,$B$4:$B$9,INDIRECT("B"&"2"))` to make it work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).